# Is it safe to keep baby in a pram on a cloudy day but with extreme UV?

Tags: sunlight

We live in NZ and nowadays UV index at noon lingers at extreme index of 11-12.

However it's quite cloudy day and we cover the pram and position it in a way that the baby wouldn't get direct exposure.

However, I feel that she still might get way too much exposure via rays dispersed by clouds (side ways) and some passing thru fabric.

Comment: Good question.  I don't know the answer.  ❧  If nobody answers within a week or two, you could [request migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site) to Health SE.  ❧  Another option would be to ask a local family doctor or dermatologist.  You could then let us know what they say by answering your own question.  ❧  If your baby is less than six months old, please follow [certain precautions](https://www.thebump.com/a/is-sunscreen-safe-for-baby) before applying sunscreen.

Answer (score 1):

It is a myth that clouds protect fro UV rays. WHO says generally some clouds can reduce the intensity but other clouds may even enhance it.

Additional protection like tree shadow, sun milk, sun umbrella is given advice. The best will be: Don’t go out between 12h and 16h. Especially not when living in N.Z. Remember the ozone hole.)

*UV levels are highest under cloudless skies, and cloud cover generally reduces a person's exposure. However, light or thin clouds have little effect and may even enhance UV levels because of scattering. Don't be fooled by an overcast day or a cool breeze! Even a long stay in open shade, for example between buildings, may give a sensitive person a sunburn on a day with high UV levels.*

https://www.who.int/uv/faq/whatisuv/en/index3.html

Comment: Ditto wrt staying in shade. We've recently got burned by spending nice couple of hours in shade, but in front of ocean. Reflection from water is intense!

Comment: That’s right. You can see the effect of the UV rays at your tan.That‘s why we better don‘t go lay in the sun. But to whom do I tell this! I did it all my life and now I‘m over 70 and skin damages are my main problem.